# android button - my first app error

Tags: android

Working on my very 1st android application or more like learning. 
I am trying to figure out an error i get below:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/save_button').

I just want to rename the button to something else like "Save Me" or "Next". But can't seem to understand how to get around it. Can't find a simple tutorial on this. Mostly involved several xml for a button. Please help. It won't let me compile and run.

Thank you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="text" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: I am using Eclipse

Comment: Add the string into string.xml <string name="save_button">Save Me</string>

Comment: By *renaming the button*, you mean the ID, or the text shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go you `res/values/` folder and open the string.xml in there. Then add the save button string in there:

sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="save_button">Button name Here</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Heelo World</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: it worked! Didn't know about the string.xml part. Learned something new today.

Comment: @user3571204 please click the check mark for correct answer

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "rename your button"?
As you described, I assumed that you want to name your button "save me" or "next".
In that way, I wonder if you have a string value "save_button"
if not, just use

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="save button" />
```

This should work.

Comment: I was using that earlier, following a video tutorial. but for some reason it didn't work and prompted an error above. Possibly it's newer version of android. I am not too sure either. :D Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3571204 why would this prompt an error? Here there's no "@string" so it shouldn't have any problems but a warning to tell you use "@string". So what you do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The android:text parameter references a resource in your strings.xml file, in your res folder. If you don't have a string named save_button referenced in strings.xml, it will cause this error.

You are **not** naming your button this way.  To name it, you would need a parameter such as:

```
android:id = "@+id/save_button"
```

So really, this is what you mean to do:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/save_button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

that means you need to add string in res/values strings.xml like this

```
<string name="hello_world">hello world.</string>
```

so that you can see hello_world in R.java and you can use it

Answer (score 0):

go to res file and in the string.xml folder add :

```
<string name="save_button">Save</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World</string>
```